# Issue with Generics and using a run-time Type, rather than (generic) T

Tags: c#, generics

To lay out the problem as easily as possible, I'm trying to implement a generic pooling system that can handle an arbitrary number of concrete classes so long as they implement `IBaseComponent`.

So, in my class that manages the pools, I have a Dictionary of Pools:

```
Dictionary<Type, Pool<IBaseComponent>> pools;
```

As this will allow me to create as many classes that implement `IBaseComponent` (which is a very 'low level' interface, so to speak - so classes implementing it are not going to be compatible too terribly far) as I want, and there can be a pool for each.

Now, the issue I'm running in to is the first load of an `IBaseComponent` into the pool, to act as a template, so to speak.

This template object is loaded from XML, rather than code, so I do not have its actual *class* at compile-time, only at run time (it's defined in the XML definition and I grab the formal Type via reflection). That's all fine and dandy except, as we know, generics rely on compile-time safety.

So, using some reflection trickery I have the following:

```
var type = typeof(MyChildComponent);
var genericType = typeof(Pool<>);
var specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(type);
var pool = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType );

pools.Add(T, pool as Pool<IBaseComponent>);
```

assuming some class:

```
public class MyChildComponent : IBaseComponent
```

The problem occurs at the last line in the first block there, when I'm adding to the pools dictionary. The cast of the instantiated pool to `Pool<IBaseComponent>` fails, resulting in null being inserted into the Dictionary.

My question to you fine folks is this: Is there any reasonable way around this? Any *possible* way, even?

If I need to load elements via some external method (XML, TXT, whatever) for at least the very first template object for a pool, for each possible concrete class that a Pool could be used for, *and* all I have access to is the top-level interface and formal Type of the class (both defined in the external definition file), can I do anything here?

Or is this simply not possible at all?

Comment: I guess this should be mentioned to extend the answer by TheEvilPenguin: *The type parameter is used only as a return type of interface methods and not used as a type of method arguments.* and *The type parameter is not used as a generic constraint for the interface methods.*. See [out (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Are you using .Net 4+?  If so, you can create an interface `IPool<out T>`.  The `out` makes the generic argument covariant, which means it will accept any version of the interface with a generic argument which is T or derives from T.

For some reason co/contravariance only works with interfaces and delegates, which is why you need IPool.

Your Dictionary will become:

```
Dictionary<Type, IPool<IBaseComponent>>() pools;
```

I'm having a little trouble combining it in my head with the reflection, but I think that should work.  If not, let me know and I'll spend a little more time on my test code.

Comment: +1: but I guess this should be mentioned: *The type parameter is used only as a return type of interface methods and not used as a type of method arguments.* and *The type parameter is not used as a generic constraint for the interface methods.*. See [out (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Comment: My bad.  The test code I wrote in LINQPad seemed to confirm my theory but it's entirely possible I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0 (but no further than that, as this is being done in XNA). Thanks for taking the time to post this, even if it may not quite work as expected (as per Konstantin's commennt).

Answer (score 1):

One alternative option I'm toying with is modifying `Pool<T>` itself.

Instead of having `Pool<T>` store only one type of (concerete) class, I will modify it to support storing any compatible class based on an interface used for T.

So, `Pool<IBaseComponent>` will be responsible for storing all possible types that implement `IBaseComponent`.

*Internally*, it will store everything as an `IBaseComponent`, but will keep references to where each concrete type is stored (in a Dictionary of lists keyed by `Type`, perhaps, or even just one big linear list [although this would make resizing the "pool" for specific types a lot more complicated])

One thing I neglected to mention is that `IBaseComponent` exposes two points of functionality that are all I need for preparing a component for use in a "blind" fashion (ie: the factory that would be calling this pool doesn't know at compile time what types of components it's working with either, it just loads them up based on what's defined in XML, or copying from an existing object that has these components attached to it), namely: `Deserialize` (build component from XML/JSON/whatever) and `CopyInto(IBaseComponent other)` (build component by copying from another component).

So, this would still have the problem that the `Pool` won't be able to dynamically cast the `IBaseComponent` to the caller's requested `Type`, but that won't matter. If the caller really knows the *hard compile-time type* ahead of time it can do the cast. If the caller doesn't, then it wouldn't be able to do anything beyond access methods exposed by `IBaseComponent` anyways.

All that matters is that the `IBaseComponent` the `Pool` returns is of the correct type underneath, which this will handle.

Put simply: I'll be cutting out a bit of modern generics (interally the Pool will only work with passed-in Types, externally it will only allow T to be an interface), and replacing it will good ol' fashioned `Type` passing. Reflection will have to be used internally to instantiate the Pool of Types, but I figure that it's okay to expect that initializing or resizing a Pool is going to be a very costly manouever.